# WM6.5 HttpWebRequest return exception connection time out while IE is able to open the process the request without a problem

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

Platform in use is Windows Mobile 6.5 with an application based in CF2.0 (Motorola MC75 device)

I am trying to send some data over to a url with some get parameters e.g.

"http://192.168.0.1:8080/myapp?param1=abcd&param2=xyz"

When I open this URL on the Internet explorer in the windows I get the expected response however when i try it in my application I get a server not reachable exception (connection timed out).

The code snippet where i get the exception is

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = null;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Now this code works on the emulator but fails on the actual device. The application is not signed and while executing when asked we allow the application to execute.